# Python SDK Azure Resource Graph response not iterable

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to query resources in Azure subscriptions using the Azure Resource Graph python SDK from within an Azure Function. The fact it's using the Functions runtime isn't important, the code also doesn't work locally.
The query itself works very well. However, I then want to use the results in a subsequent step, and that's where I'm hitting an issue.

```py
    credentials, *_ = get_azure_cli_credentials()

    subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credentials)
    subs = [sub.as_dict() for sub in subscription_client.subscriptions.list()]
    subs_list = []
    for sub in subs:
        subs_list.append(sub.get('subscription_id'))

    client = rg.ResourceGraphClient(credentials)

    request = QueryRequest(subscriptions=subs_list, query="resources | where type == 'microsoft.storage/storageaccounts'| where properties.supportsHttpsTrafficOnly == 'false'")

    response = client.resources(request)
    logging.info(response)
```

I tried the following:

```py
for resource in response:
    logging.info(resource)
```

This fails with `Exception: TypeError: 'QueryResponse' object is not iterable`.
For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resourcegraph/azure.mgmt.resourcegraph.models.queryresponse?view=azure-python

```py
logging.info(response['data'])
```

This fails with `Exception: TypeError: 'QueryResponse' object is not subscriptable`.
Anybody know how to use this response now?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response format can be simplified to match resource JSON by passing `QueryRequestOptions` :

```
client = ResourceGraphClient(credentials)

options = QueryRequestOptions(
    result_format=ResultFormat.object_array
)

request = QueryRequest(subscriptions=subs_list, query="<query>", options=options)

response = client.resources(request)

for resource in response.data:
    logging.info(resource)
```

Answer (score 1):

The result type [QueryResponse](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-mgmt-resourcegraph/2.0.0/azure.mgmt.resourcegraph.models.html#azure.mgmt.resourcegraph.models.QueryResponse) has a property `data` that you can use to access the resulting data. Since `QueryResponse` isn't a dictionary but rather a class, you can't access the data property with subscripting (square brackets). Instead you need to access it as property of the class like `response.data`.

The `data` property is a dict with two keys, `columns` which is a list of all the columns returned and the type of data each column contains, and `rows` which is a list of all of the rows in the result matching the query.

So your loop will probably look something like:

```py
for resource in response.data['rows']:
    logging.info(resource)
```